# Nginx not adding expires headers to fonts, not changing mime types

Tags: nginx, mime-type, cache-control

I have the following location block in my server block in **/etc/sites-available/example.com**:

```
    location ~* \.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
```

and this under **/etc/nginx/mime.types**:

```
types {
...
application/x-font-ttf ttc ttf;
application/x-font-otf otf;
application/font-woff woff;
application/font-woff2 woff2;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot;
...
}
```

First of all, response header content-type does not seem to change. For example, for ttf it shows **application/octet-stream**.

Most importantly, expires headers are missing. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. Chrome devtools was serving me resources from cache even though I had cleared cache in chrome. I needed to disable cache under the network tab. Everything works.